# Extract property id from attribute using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to extract property id from the following website: https://www.kwsouthafrica.co.za/Property/RouteUrl?ids=P22%2C&ForSale=ForSale&PropertyTypes=&Beds=Any&Baths=Any&MinPrice=Any&MaxPrice=Any

But whichever combination I try to use I can't seem to retrieve it.

Property id is located here:

```html
<div class="corner-ribbon">
   <span class="ribbon-green">NEW!</span>
   </div>
<a href="Details?id=182519" title="view this property">
            <img class="img-responsive img-prop" src="https://kwsadocuments.blob.core.windows.net/devblob/24c21aa4-ae17-41d1-8719-5abf8f24c766.jpg" alt="Living close to Nature">
        </a>
```

And here is what I have tried so far:

```
response.xpath('//a[@title="view this property"]/@href').getall(),
response.xpath('//*[@id="divListingResults"]/div/div/a/@href').getall(),
response.xpath('//*[@class="corner-ribbon"]/a/@href').getall()
```

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand how this page works. It loads properties using Javascript (check page source in your browser using `Ctrl+U`) and (as you know) Scrapy can't process Javascript.

But if you check page source you'll find that all information your need is "hidden" inside `<input id="propertyJson" name="ListingResults.JsonResult" >` tag. So all you need to get that `value` and process it using `json` module:

```
import scrapy
import json

class PropertySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'property_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.kwsouthafrica.co.za/Property/RouteUrl?ids=P22%2C&ForSale=ForSale&PropertyTypes=&Beds=Any&Baths=Any&MinPrice=Any&MaxPrice=Any']

    def parse(self, response):
        property_json = response.xpath('//input[@id="propertyJson"]/@value').get()
        # with open('Samples/Properties.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write(property_json)
        property_data = json.loads(property_json)
        for property in property_data:
            property_id = property['Id']
            property_title = property['Title']
            print(property_id)

        print(property_data)
```

Comment: I indeed tried that as well, however when I try 
property_json = response.xpath('//input[@id="propertyJson"]/@value').get(),
property_json is empty. And I am not sure why. @gangabass

Comment: I don't know what's wrong on your side but above code (see updated part) works perfectly for me.

Comment: I had a wrong start URL typed before somehow, now it works like a charm! Thank you very much! @gangabass